# Access 2010 query still showing results when record empty

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I am trying to make a query joining 4 tables. One table will only fill out some records, not all. How do I get the criteria to be:

If record is `null` still show the field..... because right now if the record is `null` in any one of the fields it will not show in my query results.

Comment: Put a little bit more effort explaining the problem, please. I can't understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

If records are missing in one table, then you must use an outer join. Say, you have a table A with 5 records and a table B with only 3 records and you want to make a query joining the two tables showing 5 records

```
SELECT * FROM
    A
    LEFT JOIN B
        ON A.ID = B.FK
```

In the query designer, right click on the join-line and enter this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want your filter conditions to ignore NULLs. (That is, by default a NULL wouldn't match your filter, but the desired output is that it should.)

If this is correct, you want to modify the filters to allow NULLs, for example by adding `OR IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use a LEFT (or "outer") Join instead of an INNER join.

Outer joins (like LEFT JOINs) will return all results whether there are matching records in the other table or not. You'll just have null column values in the results for the joined tables.

More info here: http://pcmcourseware.com/blog/2010/11/10/modifying-query-joins-in-microsoft-access/